# Better way to create/append to a list value in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

In the following program, I am trying to transform a dictionary into a different dictionary.

Consider the input dictionary whose *key* is filename and *value* is Author name:

```py
{'1.txt': 'Author1', '2.txt': 'Author1', '3.txt': 'Author2'}
```

The expected output is a dictionary whose *key* is Author name and *value* is a LIST of files

```py
{'Author1': ['1.txt', '2.txt'], 'Author2': ['3.txt']}
```

The following program achieves this goal:

```py
def group_by_authors(files):
    grp={}
    for fname, author in files.items():
        if author in grp:
            # if key exists, append to the value
            grp[author].append(fname)
        else:
            # if key does not exist, create a LIST value
            grp[author] = [fname]
    print(grp)

files = {
    '1.txt': 'Author1',
    '2.txt': 'Author1',
    '3.txt': 'Author2'
}

print(files)
group_by_authors(files)
```

But I would like to know if I can avoid the 'if - else' statement and directly do the 'append' (or something similar) to the list value (to an empty list if key doesnt exist).

```py
def group_by_authors(files):
    grp={}
    for fname, author in files.items():
            #single statement to set value of grp[author]
    print(grp)
```

The following does achieve the transformation:

```py
def group_by_authors(files):
    grp = defaultdict(list)
    for fname, author in files:
        grp[author].append(fname)
    print(grp)
```

but in my case I am trying to achieve it without using defaultdict.

Comment: Why not `defaultdict`?

Comment: I didnt want to resort to defaultdict unless am sure there is no way to do it with the base dict.

Comment: For the qn of whether there is a better way than defaultdict, the answer seems to be "No". But the answer from @deceze does offer an interesting alternative. So, am choosing it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`defaultdict` really is the most straight forward solution, but you can do without and use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) instead:

```
grp = {}

for file, author in files.items():
    grp.setdefault(author, []).append(file)
```

The only difference to `defaultdict` is that a) the call is a little more verbose than simply `grp[author]`, and b) the `[]` list is being created on every call, even if not used.

Answer (score 2):

Use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
out = defaultdict(list)
m = {'1.txt': 'Author1', '2.txt': 'Author1', '3.txt': 'Author2'}
for k, v in m.items():
    out[v] += [k]

print(dict(out))
#prints {'Author1': ['1.txt', '2.txt'], 'Author2': ['3.txt']}
```

Comment: Sorry. may be you missed the update I made abt not wanting to use defaultdict. Am looking for an alternate.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to cripple yourself by not using the python standard library.  (I would use the standard `.append(k)` but this should be fine)